# Does CSS calc not work on a table cell? How do I make two (of 4 column) the same width?

Tags: css

Does CSS calc not work on a table cell? If you change 90px to any size (such as 1px) that's not a 0 it will all look the same. We can calculate 800*.4 - 90 is 230, and nothing I do with calc seems to come up with that number.

What I'm trying to do is have both p column be 50% of the table size minus 90px that the t column uses

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">

 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Document</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <style>
  table { width: 800px; }
  .t { width: 90px }
  .p { 
   width: calc(40% - 90px);
   -width: 230px;
  }
 </style>
 <table>
  <tr>
  <td class="t">Thing_____</td>
  <td class="p">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
   It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
   desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
   <td class="t">Thing_____</td>
   <td class="p">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
   It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
   desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</td>
 
  </tr>
 </table>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: I have only success with such maneuver if I use max-width, min-width and width all set to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add [table-layout:fixed](http://stylescss.free.fr/v2-properties/table-layout.php#simulateur); 
This means that the widths of the columns are no longer determined by the content.

```
table { width: 800px; table-layout:fixed;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just apply `table-layout: fixed;` to the main table tag. This ensures that if the content is bigger than the set width, it won't go out of the specified width. Basically it forces to adjust in the given width. Also `calc();` works but you must know about how `%` unit behaves with tables.